# Map array items through several functions

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there a more *elegant* way then this to execute several functions in succession for each item in the array:

```ts
type Transform<T> = (o: T) => T;
type Item = { /* properties */ };

transform(input, transformers: Transform<Item>[]) {
  const items: Item[] = getItems(input);
  return items.map(item => {
    let transformed = item;
    tramsformers.forEach(t => transformed = t(transformed));
    return transformed;
  })
}
```

Comment: Define "elegant."

Comment: I don't like that local variable, but `forEach()` returns void. Not sure how to pass result of a transformation to the next one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great use case for [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
transform(input, transformers: Transform<Item>[]) {
  const items: Item[] = getItems(input);
  return items.map(item => transformers.reduce((val, transformer) => transformer(val), item));
}
```

Or perhaps more readably:

```
transform(input, transformers: Transform<Item>[]) {
  const items: Item[] = getItems(input);
  return items.map(
    item => transformers.reduce(
      (val, transformer) => transformer(val),
      item
    )
  );
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function getItems(input) {
  return [
    "abcdefg",
    "1234567"
  ];
}
function transform(input, transformers) {
  const items = getItems(input);
  return items.map(item => transformers.reduce((val, transformer) => transformer(val), item));
}
const result = transform("x", [
  v => v.toUpperCase(),
  v => v.substring(1, v.length - 1)
]);
console.log(result);
```

As Nitzan Tomer points out, we could do away with the `items` constant:

```
transform(input, transformers: Transform<Item>[]) {
  return getItems(input).map(
    item => transformers.reduce(
      (val, transformer) => transformer(val),
      item
    )
  );
}
```

I frequently keep those sorts of things for debugging, but some good debuggers now make it easy to see the return value of functions before they return (Chrome's does), so if you removed it, you could step into `getItems` to see the items before the `map`.

Comment: There's also no need for the `items` const, it can be a one liner without it.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: Indeed, it's not necessary, but I don't think that was the focus of the question. (For my own code, I'd probably leave it there to make debugging easier; it'll get optimized out anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a bit more reusable version, based on @T.J.Crowder's answer:

```ts
export type Transform<T> = (o: T) => T;
export function pipe<T>(sequence: Transform<T>[] = []) {
  return (item: T) => sequence.reduce((value, next) => next(value), item);
}

transform(input, transformers?) {
  return getItems(input).map( pipe(transformers) );
}
```

Note that type is inferred from `getItems(input)` and return type is `transform(): Item[]`.